# Rsync using absolute paths

Tags: rsync, rhel7

I have two RHEL 7 servers.

On my Source I have the following directories

```
/sourcestuff/testresync
/sourcestuff/testresync/incl1
/sourcestuff/testresync/incl1/test1.txt
/sourcestuff/testresync/incl2
/sourcestuff/testresync/incl2/test2.txt
/sourcestuff/testresync/excl3
/sourcestuff/testresync/excl3/test2.txt
/sourcestuff/testresync/excl4
/sourcestuff/testresync/excl4/test2.txt
```

On my Destination I have the following directories

```
/destinationstuff/testresync
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl1
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl2
/destinationstuff/testresync/excl3
/destinationstuff/testresync/excl4
```

What I am trying to do is copy the data from my Source to my Destination and exclude the /sourcestuff/testresync/excl3 and /sourcestuff/testresync/excl4 from the Source

What I have tried

```
rsync -av --relative /sourcestuff/testrsync/./ --exclude '/sourcestuff/testrsync/excl3/' --exclude '/sourcestuff/testrsync/excl4/' user@SERVERIP:/destinationstuff/testrsync
```

I have read the documentation that the -exclude option relies on the source but everything I try the excl3 and excl4 data still gets transferred.

I have also tried the other way does not work

What I want my Destination to look like:

```
/destinationstuff/testresync
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl1
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl1/test1.txt  
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl2
/destinationstuff/testresync/incl2/test2.txt
/destinationstuff/testresync/excl3
/destinationstuff/testresync/excl4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, when you use `--relative` then normally a source path like `/a/b/` will get reproduced at a destination of `/d` as `/d/a/b/`, and to exclude directory `/a/b` you would use `--exclude /a/b/`.

However, when you add the `/./` to the source path, like `/a/./b/` then only the part after the dot is copied, i.e. you get `/d/b/`.  **But, the exclude path has to change too**, to be only the part after the dot, `--exclude /b/`.

So modify your exclude patterns to something like `/excl3/`.